# Is there a way I can know which all permission should I ask from a user for google play to accept my app?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I don't exactly know which permissions should I ask for in manifest. Is there a tool where I can put my code and it can tell me exactly which all permissions should I ask for in manifest.

I tried to read the whole code and use google to get to know if permission is required but didn't got much information.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I expect the result should be name of a tool or technique by which I can know which all permission should I ask for so that my application can be approved by google play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest permissions have nothing to do with play store acceptance.  If a permission isn't asked for in the Manifest and the app tries to use it, the app won't work-  the device will either return bad data (for example null), or throw an Exception.  The Play Store reports to the user what permissions you've asked for, but it doesn't check your app-  the device does.

Answer (score 1):

Dark ones are permission groups, others are permissions you need.
 [A list of all Android permissions](https://gist.github.com/Arinerron/1bcaadc7b1cbeae77de0263f4e15156f)

**CALENDAR**
READ_CALENDAR,
WRITE_CALENDAR

**CALL_LOG**
READ_CALL_LOG,
WRITE_CALL_LOG,
PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS

**CAMERA**
CAMERA

**CONTACTS**
READ_CONTACTS,
WRITE_CONTACTS,
GET_ACCOUNTS

**LOCATION**
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

**MICROPHONE**
RECORD_AUDIO

**PHONE**
READ_PHONE_STATE,
READ_PHONE_NUMBERS,
CALL_PHONE,
ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS,
ADD_VOICEMAIL,
USE_SIP

**SENSORS** 
BODY_SENSORS

**SMS** 
SEND_SMS,
RECEIVE_SMS,
READ_SMS,
RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH,
RECEIVE_MMS

**STORAGE** 
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Spinner spinner;
FirebaseFirestore db;
FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
DatabaseHelper myDb;
ProgressDialog dialog1;
PermissionManager permissionManager;
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout; 
OnItemClickListener mListener;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
ObjectAnimator animator
DisplayMetrics dm
Cipher cipher
MessageDigest digest
DocumentReference docRef

Which permissions should I use for these?

Comment: @Anshul You only need internet permission.

Comment: Spinner spinner; FirebaseFirestore db; FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics; FirebaseAuth mAuth; DatabaseHelper myDb; ProgressDialog dialog1; PermissionManager permissionManager; SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout; OnItemClickListener mListener; SharedPreferences sharedPreferences; ObjectAnimator animator DisplayMetrics dm Cipher cipher MessageDigest digest DocumentReference docRef Which permissions should I use for these?

Comment: @Anshul There is such a situation. You will determine permissions based on the actions you will use. For example you need to access the internet to connect to firebase. You just need to get internet access. However, if you want to save the data you receive from the firebase to the device, then you need to get WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: @Anshul If you want to read a file from the device. For example, if you want to list photos or open a text document, the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission will be required. You must evaluate permissions by permission groups.